# Разбор по составу имён собственных

Tags: словообразование, ономастика, морфемика, склонение-фамилий

Выделяются ли в составе имён собственных какие-либо морфемы, кроме корня и окончания?

Например, фамилия *Водовозов*. Можно рассматривать производящую основу *водовоз*, которая членится на морфемы, но делить на части само существительное *Водовозов* мне кажется нелогичным.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы правы, нелогично, когда-то семантические связи были: Водовозов — сын водовоза. А Лужин тогда кто? — тот, кто упал в лужу? И в фамилии Задорожный нелогично выделять приставку за- и суфф -н-: Задорожн/ый.

Нет, в фамилиях нет приставок и суффиксов с точки зрения современного словообразования (этимологически, конечно же, выделяются патронимические суффиксы). [Как определять корни в фамилиях? Например, что является корнем в фамилии Лановой? | gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=201291)

Так что: Водовозов/нулев. оконч., Водовозов/а.

Суффиксы есть в именах: Свет/а, Свет/очк/а, Свет/ик/нул. оконч.